# git logs are missing when they are on the branching node

Tags: git

Let's see if I can describe this well.
We are using GitFlow so we have a DEV branch and the developers have feature branches. They make PRs and QA completes the PRs based on availability. That gets branched to a QA_Release that gets built and deployed.

Anyway, I have noticed that if someone builds the DEV branch (which gets tagged with a build number) then I branch to a QA_Release and build that (which gets tagged with the next build number) when I try to get the log comments I miss the PR that was on the node that got branched.

```
1(tag)   2(tag)
|________x_________
          \________
                  |
                  3(tag)
```

If the commit at x gets built and tagged then branched when I do 'git log 2..3' the PR description from 2 doesn't show. If I use 'git log 2~..3' it shows.

Is that supposed to be happening?

Comment: I guess this is just a misunderstanding from your part. Do `git log --help` and read the part about revision ranges. `git log aaa..bbb` should according to the documentation print all "commits that are reachable from `bbb` but exclude those that are reachable from `aaa`". In other words, the range `aaa..bbb` does not include the commit `aaa`.

Comment: Ok, then how do I include aaa? Are we left with using the ~ (parent)? Sometimes that gets me more than I need. There's 7 different ways to exclude stuff from git log but I don't see a way to include stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is basically how commit ranges work.

When you say this:

```
A..B
```

You actually say this:

```
^A B
```

Which means "everything that is reachable from B, excluding everything that is reachable from A". This last part includes A, so thus it is not part of the log.

When you say "2~", you say "Parent of 2", thus you say "... excluding everything that is reachable from the parent of 2". This does **not** include 2.

Please note that this has nothing to do with gitflow, nor with your branches or pull requests, that's just how the double dot syntax works.

You can read the documentation for the range here:

[The .. (two-dot) Range Notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation)

Comment: I will accept this as an answer but, this can't be the best way. Inclusion by "lack of exclusion" is not a good way to indicate stuff. How is there not a good way to say "From A to B inclusive"? Unless there is and it was hidden in the depths of non-exclusionary examples on that page.
But, thanks for the help.